# Is every dense complete endless linearly ordered subset of real order-isomorphic to real?

Tags: real-numbers, order-theory

Let $(M,\leq)$ be a non-empty

- dense ($\forall a<b\in M,\exists c\in M,a<c<b$),
- complete (every non-empty subset that is bounded above has a supreme)
- endless (there is no minimal or maximal element)

linearly(totally) ordered subset of $(\mathbb{R},\leq)$. Do we have that $M$ is order-isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$?

The context is to show that $(\mathbb{R},\leq )$ is the minimal non-empty dense complete endless linearly ordered set up to order-isomorphism, which is a corollary of this problem.

Comment: I *think* that the answer is no: see [the long line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_(topology)#:~:text=In%20topology%2C%20the%20long%20line,is%20neither%20Lindelöf%20nor%20separable).

Comment: @Joe, the long line is not a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, which is what makes this an interesting question.

Comment: @Jephph: Apologies, I missed that hypothesis in Z Wu's question.

Comment: Related: Souslin's problem `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suslin%27s_problem`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it.

The real numbers is the unique non-empty linear order which is complete, dense and separable.
It suffices to show that $M$ is separable with the order topology $\tau_{\leq}$.

Since $\mathbb{R}$ is a separable metric space and [subspace of separable metric space is separable](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Subspace_of_Separable_Metric_Space_is_Separable), it follows that $M$ is separable with the subspace topology $\tau_M$, i.e. there exists a countable sequence $\{x_n:n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ s.t. $\forall U\in \tau_M,\{x_n:n\in \mathbb{N}\}\cap U=\emptyset$.

Also we have [the subspace topology is finer than the order topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1714252/order-topology-vs-subspace-topology), i.e. $\tau_{\leq}\subset \tau_M$, it follows that $M$ is separable with the order topology as well. The result follows.

Comment: For a counterexample when you remove the separable condition take $[0,1]^2 \setminus \{ (0,0), (1,1)\} $ with the lexicografic order i.e. $ (a,b) < (c, d) $ iif $ a < c$ or $ c = a \land  b< d$. The box has uncountably many disjoint intervals.